# Changing membership category. Does that effect auto-recurring payment system?

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

I am wanting to change the category of a auto-renewing monthly membership and am wondering if changing the actual membership category effects this or not?

How does a payment processor communicate with CiviCRM to do this anyway?

Thanks all!

Andy Burns

Comment: What payment processor are you using @Andy?